# How to use VBA to change "checked" property of radio buttons on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel

I am using VBA to allow Excel to navigate through some web pages and extract data from them.  On one page, I need to change which of two radio buttons is checked before proceeding.  Unfortunately, the individual radio buttons in the group do not have specified IDs.  Is there an index assigned to the radio buttons by default that I can use to identify which one I want to be checked?  How do I do this in VBA?

Here is source code from the web page.  Initially the first radio button is checked.  I want to change the second one to checked before clicking the sbmSearch button.

```
<table class="Searchstyle">
   <tr>
      <td>Search by
         <input type="radio" name="rdoSearchBy" value="Report" checked> Report No or 
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="radio" name="rdoSearchBy" value="Author"> Author 
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="submit" name="sbmSearch" value="Search">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
With oIE ' my InternetExplorer object
   .
   .
   With .Document.all
      '.rdoGiren.Author.Checked = True ' attempt 1 - error
      .getElementsByName("rdoSearchBy")(1).Checked = True ' attempt 2 - error
      .sbmSearch.Click  ' Clicks the Search button
   End With
   Do While .Busy: DoEvents:  Loop
   Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
   .
   .
End With
```

I figure there's got to be a way to do this, I'm just not finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seeing if VBA allows something like this?

```
    With .Document.all
      .getElementsByClassName("Searchstyle")(0)(1)(0).Checked = True ' attempt 2 - error
      .sbmSearch.Click  ' Clicks the Search button
```

That way you just work your way down the children elements of the table.

Comment: Garrett, thanks for the suggestion, but I got an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error when I tried.  It seems IE8 doesn't support the getElementsByClassName() method, and the IT dept has us locked down to IE8.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, developing for those older versions of IE can be a real pain.